# ruby : unsupported parameters: :order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able to install this app on my windows 7 laptop https://github.com/cheezy/puppies

But now when I am trying to access it at `localhost:3000` it is giving me error:
`unsupported parameters: :order`
[image]

I went to the file in this app and found this code:

**app/controllers/agency_controller.rb**

```
class AgencyController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize

  def index
    @puppies = Puppy.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => 4
  end

end
```

While looking for a fix on this error I found a fix here https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/500

Where a comment by "mislav" says that "Active Record doesn't support `:xyz` formatting and it need to be written in `User.where(conditions).order('title').per_page(per_page).page(page)` format.

So, if it is a fix how to write `@puppies = Puppy.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => 4` in suggested format?

But if its not actual fix how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because you are passing `:order` into the `paginate` method.

The correct query should be:

`@puppies = Puppy.order(:name).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)`

Comment: It worked but new error came up now `Could not find table 'puppies'` any help on that  :)

Comment: You didn't setup the project properly.

The standard procedure after downloading a Rails project is to run the following commands: `bundle && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`.
Which will install gem dependencies, create your database and then add table definitions into it. This project also has seed data. You can seed your project's database with: `rake db:seed`.

Comment: awesome it worked. I did rails s after successfully executing `bundle && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`. What `rake db:seed` does?

Comment: Basically, it runs db/seeds.rb for you. This file is used for seeding initial data into your application. Usually you'll create records and create associations between them.

Comment: that also worked now I can see puppies and details but can't complete an order it says `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I can't really tell you what it is since this error message is too generic. Probably it isn't loading your record in the controller. It's just a guess, though. However, this project is quite old. I really suggest you to find a newer one. You'll be able to find some here: https://github.com/ekremkaraca/awesome-rails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149509/discussion-between-paul-and-caioeps).